# Remove up vote without lock-in

Tags: discussion, voting, locked-votes

I recently up voted an answer to a question because it seemed accurate based on the information provided. I spent more time looking into the issue myself and now it seems the answer was not fully correct. I don't necessarily want to DOWN vote the answer, but it does not merit the up vote.

I understand some of the reasons behind locking in votes, but I'm not trying to do a full swing, just un-do the vote I had given. Is there a good reason this shouldn't be allowed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a good reason.  The votes can't be retracted without at least a trivial edit to prevent people from strategically voting, either upvoting questions to get their answers more attention or downvoting other competing answers and then removing the downvote later on to get the -1 rep back.

You can make a trivial edit, once you have 2k rep, if you have a good reason for reverting the vote, or you can note in comments that you regret the vote now for [reasons] - perhaps suggesting to the answerer to fix said problem.

Comment: What you describe sounds like a legitimate problem. Unfortunately, by locking votes, a new problem is created. Maybe another solution to the actual problem can allow this workaround to be lifted?